# Reduce number of conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have this long list of conditions inside a function:

```
if x == "a":
    return function_a()
elif "b" in x:
    return function_b()
elif x == "c string":
    return function_c()
elif x == "d string":
    return function_d()
else:
    function_e()
```

How can I simplify this so that I can reduce the cognitive complexity of my function?

Comment: the conditions are orthogonal and well defined there is no overlap, so as is it is fine. However one can condense the if else in more pythonic way (eg using a list) but I doubt this will reduce the cognitive complexity (which is not very high though)

Comment: `if x == '...': ...` can be mapped to `{'a': function_a, 'c string': function_c, ...}[x]()`. Then you just need to handle the other cases separately.

Comment: Are these all the kinds of tests you want to reduce? As others have mentioned, tests of the form ``x == b`` can be easily converted to a ``dict`` – more complex cases such as ``"b" in x``, ``isinstance(x, int)``, ``len(x) < 5`` cannot. So it is very important to know what you actually want to simplify.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes I know the dict conversion trick, but I also wanted to simplify complex cases like you've mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
def function_a():
    print("First function")
    
def function_b():
    print("Second function")
    
x = 'b'
fns = {'a': function_a, 'b': function_b}
fns[x]()
```

Python doesn't have a switch statement so a common alternative is using a dictionary to "choose" which option to take. In this example, the values that you expect `a,b,c,d...` are the keys in a dictionary and the corresponding function is the value of that key.

To execute the correct function, you just need to access the dictionary with `fns[x]` which returns a function, and then call the function with the `()` brackets.

Comment: Great answer that could be even better with an explanation of what you've done and roughly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on this:

```
def function_a():
  return 'a'

def function_b():
  return 'b'

def function_c():
  return 'c'

def function_d():
  return 'd'

def function_e():
  print('e')

x = 'b'

L = {
  'a': function_a(),
  'c string': function_c(),
  'd string': function_d()
}

def reduced():
  try:
    L[x]()
  except KeyError:
    if 'b' in x:
      return function_b()
    else:
      function_e()

print(reduced())
```

If anyone could improve it?